# String for text issue in python

Tags: python, string

I met some problems about try to use string in text.
here is a provided file sqroot2_10kdigits.txt.
the sqroot2_10kdigits.txt is below:

> 1.4142135623 7309504880 1688724209 6980785696 7187537694 8073176679 7379907324 7846210703 8850387534 3276415727 3501384623 0912297024
> 9248360558 5073721264 4121497099 9358314132 2266592750 5592755799
> 9505011527 8206057147 0109559971 6059702745 3459686201 4728517418
> 6408891986 0955232923 0484308714 3214508397 6260362799 5251407989
> 6872533965 4633180882 9640620615 2583523950 5474575028 7759961729
> 8355752203 3753185701 1354374603 4084988471

My code is below:

```
myfile = open("sqroot2_10kdigits.txt")
txt = myfile.read()
print(txt)
myfile.close()
```

Q2: Make a new empty string called sqroot_2_string. Note that there's a space between every 10 digits.Instead of using the .rstrip() method, try using .replace(" ", "") to remove all the spaces in the file and save it in the empty string I just made. Check the length of the string as well, it should be 10002. Then print the first 10 digits followed by .... Here's an example:
The first 10 digit of square root of 2 is 1.4142135623... My codes are below:

```
def sqroot_2_string(string):
  
    
    count = 0
  
    list = []

    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        if string[i] != ' ':
            list.append(string[i])
  
    return toString(list)
  
# Utility Function
def toString(List):
    return ''.join(List)
  
# Driver program
string = myfile
print sqroot_2_string(string)
```

Anyone can check my code in Q2? *I don't know how to use .replace(" ", "") to remove all the spaces in the file and save it in the empty string*

Comment: Python2 is outdated a long time now. Use python3!

Comment: how to do it in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```py
def sqroot_2_string(string):
    return string.replace(" ", "")
```

Also note that you should do

```
print(sqroot_2_string(txt))
```

so you are using the text from the file instead of the file handle

Comment: how to Check the length of the string?, and I want to print the first 10 digits followed by : The first 10 digit of square root of 2 is 1.4142135623..

Comment: `len(string)` for the length. `string[:12]` to get the first 12 characters which are 10 digits after the comma.

Comment: print(txt[:12]) can only out put one figure, that is "1.4142135623", how to fix this problem?

Comment: print('The first 10 digit of square root of 2 is', txt[:12])  can only out put one figure, that is "1.4142135623", how to fix this problem?

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted? What is the problem?

Comment: I guess so.. but the first figure is a float number. .. so...the output is ..But you are right!